# getHTMLLinks - failed to load external entity

Tags: r, entity, external

I'm studying web scraping and I'm following the book Automated Data Collection With R.

In one example, I tried:

```
url <- ("http://elections.maryland.gov/elections/2012/election_data/index.html")
links <- getHTMLLinks(url)
```

but the answer always is:

> Error: failed to load external entity "http://elections.maryland.gov/elections/2012/election_data/index.html"

I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: If this is about R then it would probably be best to add the R tag so that people who know R can find it.

Comment: Can you definitely access the URL from the system on which you are running your code?

Comment: Could you edit this to show any other libraries/packages you have loaded? If you run library()$results[,1] it will show all the libraries you have loaded.